Cosmos db point read latency is above 20 ms for 1 RU documents
we are using cosmos db in our asp net core apis and we realized that we are not seeing the low latency for point reads that is advertised. It is stable at around 20-25 ms for point reads. Im looking at the insights on the cosmos resource.
The SLA says that we should see <10 ms for P99 and a median at around 4-5 ms.
Locally we get around 2-3 ms on average, but sometimes as low as below 1 ms.
Our setup is one app service running windows (code deploy) in North europe on a P1mV3 app service plan (so plenty of performance).
Cosmos Db NoSql running serverless in North Europe.
We are running the latest .net client on .net 8, using direct connection mode with bulk mode disabled.
The read cost is 1 RU.
I have been trying to find reasons why it is like this, but all I have found are things we are already doing.
What are we missing?
Here is a sample of our code that is producing these results:
using Azure.Monitor.OpenTelemetry.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;
using System.Diagnostics;
namespace CosmosTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        static string? _dbId;
        static string? _containerId;
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            builder.Services.AddSingleton(serviceProvider =>
            {
                var configuration = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();

                _dbId = configuration["CosmosDB:DatabaseId"];
                _containerId = configuration["CosmosDB:ContainerId"];
                var cosmosClientOptions = new CosmosClientOptions
                {
                    SerializerOptions = new CosmosSerializationOptions
                    {
                        PropertyNamingPolicy = CosmosPropertyNamingPolicy.CamelCase
                    },
                    ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,

                    AllowBulkExecution = false,
                };
                var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("Cosmos");
                return new CosmosClient(connectionString);
            });

            builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetry().WithTracing(tracerProviderBuilder =>
            {
                tracerProviderBuilder.AddSource("Azure.Cosmos.Operation");

            }).UseAzureMonitor();

            builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
            builder.Logging.AddApplicationInsights();

            var app = builder.Build();

            app.MapGet("/{partitionKey}/{id}", async (Guid id, Guid partitionKey, CosmosClient cosmosClient, ILogger<Program> logger) =>
            {
                var container = cosmosClient.GetContainer(_dbId, _containerId);

                var startTime = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();

                var itemResponse = await container.ReadItemAsync<Product>(id.ToString(), new PartitionKey(partitionKey.ToString()));

                var elapsed = Stopwatch.GetElapsedTime(startTime);

                logger.LogInformation("Read item {id} from container {container} in {elapsed} ms", id, _containerId, elapsed);

                return Results.Ok(itemResponse.Resource);

            });

            app.MapGet("/{partitionKey}", async (Guid partitionKey, CosmosClient cosmosClient) =>
            {
                var container = cosmosClient.GetContainer(_dbId, _containerId);
                var query = new QueryDefinition("SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.productBlueprintId = @productBlueprintId")
                    .WithParameter("@productBlueprintId", partitionKey);
                var iterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<Product>(query);
                var results = new List<Product>();
                while (iterator.HasMoreResults)
                {
                    var response = await iterator.ReadNextAsync();
                    results.AddRange(response.ToList());
                }
                return Results.Ok(results);
            });

            app.MapPost("/", async (Product product, CosmosClient cosmosClient) =>
            {
                var container = cosmosClient.GetContainer(_dbId, _containerId);
                var response = await container.CreateItemAsync(product, new PartitionKey(product.productBlueprintId.ToString()));
                return;
            });

            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            app.Run();
        }
    }

    public record Product(string id, Guid productBlueprintId, string Name, Guid OwnerId, DateTime createdUtc, Guid createdBy);
}

Edit: during additional testing for this repro I found that the writes are actually below 10 ms every time, its just the reads that are slow.

Please share a [mcve].

Added sample. This assumes you having a cosmos and an app service running.

Are you measuring the latency over an hour or just 1 operation? There can be a lot of reasons, have you looked at the official document for slow operations? https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/troubleshoot-dotnet-sdk-slow-request?tabs=cpu-new#application-design.

Im looking at historical data under the insights tab on the cosmos resource as well.
In the last 30 days, the lowest latency according to azure was 17 ms.
The average per hour was 20-25 ms.
And yes, I have also looked at that documentation. I have read a lot of official performance tweaking/troubleshooting documentation.

So it looks like it has to do with the serverless tier.
I have tested a few different things and having serverless always hurts the latency.
The documentation is a bit sneaky where they say that the point reads are <10 ms for both, but the provisioned are covered by an SLA (service level agreement) and the serverless is covered by a SLO (service level objective).
Moving to a provisioned tier gives 2-4 ms response times, with a few exceptions. Like promised.
